# Functions from $R \to R$ which oscilate around a value in the co-domain before diverging?

Tags: real-analysis

What are some types of functions from the reals to the reals which oscillate around a point in the co-domain before eventually diverging?

Comment: With a piecewise function, this is trivially easy to make. Just define $f(x) = \sin(x)$ for $|x| \le M$ (and make $M$ as large as you want), and define $f(x)$ to be a divergent function otherwise, e.g. $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Or truncate the Taylor series of $\sin x$ to get a degree-$n$ polynomial.